# How to make editText error onclick? (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an EditText with an input filter.

```
user.error = "Number Should Have At Least 8 Digits"
```

I would like the popup error message to stay hidden until I press the error icon on the TextView

[image: Error popup showing before pressing it]

Is it possible?

Comment: Could be more specific

Comment: editText.error = "error message" 
when an error message is set it pops up on the screen ,I would like it to stay hidden until i press on the error button will try to add a picture.

Comment: I think you need a custom implementation of TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
When you press the EditText for type something it's focused on the clicked EditText and after press the button it is still focused. Error message show up when focused the label. You can use this code;

```
user.apply { 
    error = "Number Should Have At Least 8 Digits"
    clearFocus() 
}
```